# MediaElement.js stop all players

Tags: javascript, html, media, html5-audio, mediaelement.js

I've been playing around with MediaElement.js for a while now and have a new application that uses 20 players on a single page. I'd like to be able to have the songs stop when another one is played - and not to overlap the tracks when they are playing. I can't seem to find an easy way to hack this - perhaps someone knows of a way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

In jQuery, you could do

```
$('video,audio').each(function() {
      $(this)[0].pause();
});
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: John that definite't didn't work, however console seems to be finding all the elements (it spits out a list of elements). It also doesn't throw an error...which is a good sign. But the players don't stop!

Comment: i was able to pause by taking out the player reference: $(this)[0].pause();

Comment: @starpause is right, remove "player" from before "pause" and it works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A quick and dirty one ;)

```
$(".mejs-play").live('click',function(){
  $(".mejs-pause").trigger('click');                              
});
```

Answer (score 3):

MediaElement.js creates a global object 'mejs' which has attribute 'players' which contains information about all players you`ve been created. Players are named mep_0, mep_1 etc.

If you are using underscore/lodash you can write something like

```
_.each(mejs.players, function(player) {
    player.media.stop();
});
```

If you need pure js code you can use 'for' operator

```
for (var player in mejs.players) {
    mejs.players[player].media.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest I found with jQuery:

```
$('video,audio').trigger('pause');
```

One-liner for the win!
It also avoid JS **errors** because it doesn't target directly the elements, thanks jQuery.

Comment: simple and effective